# Тестирование Jest функционала использующего fetch api

Tags: typescript, юнит-тесты, jest

Написал обертку для одного API на ts и собирался его протестировать. В целом все интеграции прошли успешно, кроме ошибки в ts-jest `fetch is not defined`. Я пробовал и '`node-fetch`' и '`cross-fetch`', все советы в интернете складываются в одно - вам не нужно обращаться к реальному серверу при тестировании, сделайте мок объекта и получайте фейковые данные.

Так то оно так, но мне то как раз нужно в моих тестах обратиться к серверу и посмотреть работает ли моя обертка над их API. То есть вся загвоздка именно в этом. Я не смотря на то, что интегрировал '`cross-fetch`' и он удачно отрабатывает в приложении, все ровно не могу использовать его, так как запуская тест мне пишет - `fetch is not defined`. И не важно, что это за fetch, из браузерного API из Node или еще какой-то...

Comment: какую версию nodejs используете? Начиная с 18.0.0 fetch уже реализован

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA 14.8.0 По идее, если я переключусь на 18.0, то проблема должна исчезнуть. То есть люди, кто использует node 18+ уже не нуждаются в node-fetch в принципе?

Comment: Понимаю, что немного не вовремя ) , но аналогичная проблема `fetch is not defined` для тестирования. 
Как Вы решили ее, поделитесь кусочком кода из теста? 
Вижу, там в ответе `Нужно использовать полифил...` , но еще не на столько силен в JS  , чтоб найти сам ответ

Comment: @Tryd0g0lik введи в консоли `node -v`, если увидишь версию node.js меньшую, чем 18, то тебе нужно обновить ее просто, как обновить загугли

Comment: И так ее знаю. Она 18+ )

Comment: @Tryd0g0lik обрати внимание на то, что у тебя может быть не одна версия node установлена на комп, какую использует функционал тестирования? Там в настройках ты должен указать путь до файла

Comment: Спасибо. Да, видел на youtube подобное.  Разобрался с ним . Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать полифил для `fetch` на стороне node.js или использовать node.js версии 18 и выше.

Дополню свой ответ спустя время:

Тестировать функционал API делая настоящие запросы на API не всегда обоснованное решение. Лучше все же замокать данные и использовать их в своем функционале. На сервере должны быть свои тесты при отдаче данных, нет смысла проверять их при приеме данных на frontend-е. Если вы тестируете таким образом и вовсе не свое API, а какое нить стороннее, то это совсем не правильно. Вы не в ответе за кривые данные, что могут упасть к вам. Выша задача проверить свой функционал на корректную работу с той сигнатурой данных, которую обязуются отдать.